# OkHttpClient successfully retrieves data from API, but on enqueue onFailure is called in Kotlin Android application

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I am trying to retrieve data from the server using retrofit2 in Kotlin in Android Studio and I get this message:
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> GET https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?&i=chicken_breast
--> END GET
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 200 https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?&i=chicken_breast (1251ms)

and it also retrieves the data I wanted, but it calls the onFailure function:
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"meals":[{"strMeal":"Chick-Fil-A Sandwich","strMealThumb":"https://www.themealdb.com/images/media/meals/sbx7n71587673021.jpg","idMeal":"53016"}]}
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (1313-byte body)
I/System.out: Fail

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener  {

    val menuAPI = MenuAPI.create()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val searchButton:Button = findViewById(R.id.searchButton)
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(this)
    }


    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        menuAPI.getResults("chicken_breast").enqueue(object: retrofit2.Callback<ArrayList<Meals>>{

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<Meals>>, t: Throwable) {
                println()
                println("Fail")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ArrayList<Meals>>, response: Response<ArrayList<Meals>>) {
                println("yes")
            }
        })

    }
}
```

```
interface MenuAPI {
    @GET("filter.php?")
    fun getResults(@Query("i") ingredient:String ): Call<ArrayList<Meals>>

    companion object {
        private val httpInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            // there are different logging levels that provide a various amount of detail
            // we will use the most detailed one
            this.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        }
        private val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
            // add the interceptor to the newly created HTTP client
            this.addInterceptor ( httpInterceptor )
        }.build()

        fun create(): MenuAPI {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl ( "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/" )
                .addConverterFactory ( GsonConverterFactory.create() )
                .client ( httpClient )
                .build()
            return retrofit.create(MenuAPI::class.java)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JSON you posted it seems the return type of your `getResults` function is wrong. The API is not returning a `List<Meals>`, but an object with a single property called `meals` which is a list of meals.

I'm not sure what your `Meals` class looks like, but you need a wrapper object to properly represent the response. Something like:

```
data class Response(val meals: List<Meals>)
```

The function will then be:

```
fun getResults(@Query("i") ingredient: String): Call<Response>
```

Here I'm assuming your `Meals` class represents a single object in the list.